# Can't set cookie 'expires' or 'maxAge' in Node.js using Express 3.0

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, cookies, express

I've been trying to set my cookie's expiry date in Node.js using Express 3.0, but nothing is working.

My first attempt:

```
res.cookie('user', user, { maxAge: 9000, httpOnly: true });
```

Just ends in a cookie that has an invalid expiry time according to Chrome.
Then I tried to set 'expires' instead, like so:

```
res.cookie('user', user, { expires: new Date(new Date().getTime()+5*60*1000), httpOnly: true });
```

And now my cookie is just a session cookie.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. your question along with this link brought me to a solution i was looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use `req.session.cookie`:

```
req.session.cookie.expires = false;

req.session.cookie.maxAge = 5 * 60 * 1000;
```

See also [connect docs](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html).

Comment: Turns out: it was actually working. Chrome just says the time format is wrong, but it still honours it.

Answer (score 59):

Do note that maxAge is in milliseconds-

```
res.cookie('jwtToken', token, { maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000, httpOnly: true }); // maxAge: 2 hours
```

Comment: Upvote for the comment on maxAge being in millisecs!

Comment: probably the most important answer.

Comment: I was trying to use a short-lived cookie during development (120s), and got errors about 'Cookie “<cookieName>” has been rejected because it is already expired.' I was actually setting the maxAge to 120ms, which had expired by the time the page loaded. This wasn't easy to find searching, since Express uses ms, but [browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) implement [RFC 6265](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-5.2.2) that uses seconds; it's somewhat unexpected that Express does the conversion instead of just passing the value through.

Comment: A strange decision to make it milliseconds considering the standard is seconds.. I'm guessing that decision has cost countless hours.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me.. but the original question has the version that does work. For example

```
var language = 'en';
//10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 === 315360000000, or 10 years in milliseconds
var expiryDate = new Date(Number(new Date()) + 315360000000); 
this.__res.cookie('lang', language, { expires: expiryDate, httpOnly: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
res.cookie('cookieName', jsonObject, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + (30*24*3600000)) }); /*set 1month,
```

If you face any issue related to cookie expire initialization, then debug your-self, I had to debug myself and fixed it as follows:

- Insert the initialized time into a new variable

```js
var expiryDate = new Date(Date.now() + (60*24*3600000));
console.log(expiryDate);
```

- if it's display as aspected, then look into `cookieParser npm v`