# Cookie not going through

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, express

I'm trying to set a cookie in the express framework, but it isn't going through, and for the life of me I can't figure out why. The relevant code looks like this:

```
    module.exports = function(app) {
      return function(req, res, next) {
        if (req.cookies.user_token) {
          req.session.cookie.httpOnly = false
          res.cookie('user_token', req.cookies.user_token, { domain: 'www.example.com', httpOnly: false, path: '/', maxAge: 900000 });
        }
        return res.redirect('https://www.example.com/index.jsp?other_stuff=value');
      }
    }
```

I can see the request going out, and that cookie is NOT getting set. I've stepped through with a debugger, and I know for certain that code is getting hit.

I found this question:

[How to set cookie in node js using express framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework)

Based on that, I tried calling `var express = require('express'); app.use(express.cookieParser());` earlier in the code, but it didn't seem to make any difference.

Anybody have any ideas where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: Since `if (req.cookies.user_token) {` wraps the code that sets the cookie, it looks like you are checking that the cookie exists before setting it. So it never gets created.

Comment: @Trott: Nope. I'm looking to see if that cookie exists for the page I'm already on; if it does, I want it recreated for the page I'm going to. I'm 100% certain res.cookie is getting called; I'm stepping through it with a debugger.

Comment: And the page you are redirecting to is in the same domain as the page that is setting the cookie?

Comment: @Trott: ... and that's almost certainly the problem. I didn't think that mattered, but as that redirect is actually sent back to the browser and not handled by the server, it most certainly does. Argh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the redirected domain (say, `www.example.com`) is (as indicated in the comments) different from the domain that is trying to set the cookie (say, `www.foo.io`), then the cookie will not be honored by the browser.