# Unable to create a cookie using express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I am trying to create a cookie every time a new user registers for my app, indicating that it is their first time logged in it.
I have found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework) and roughly followed it but it isn't working.

Here is my current code:

```
// setting up the middle ware
export default function () {
  return function () {
    const app = this
    app.use(cookieParser())
    app.post('/app/signup/end', [firstTimeCookie(app), signUp(app)])
  }
}
```

The middleware that isn't working is `firstTimeCookie()`, `signUp()` works fine.

```
// in firstTimeCookie:

export default function (app) {
  return function (req, res, next) {
    const cname = 'FIRST_SIGNUP'
    const cvalue = true
    var cookie = req.cookies.cookieName

    if (!cookie) {
      res.cookie(cname, cvalue, { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 999999 })
    } else {
      console.log('cookie already exists')
    }
    next()
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you add a debug point and check if your code is reaching the default function in firstTimeCookie

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `cookie` is `undefined`.

Change:

```
var cookie = req.cookies.cookieName
```

For:

```
var cookie = req.cookies['FIRST_SIGNUP'];
```

Then you'll be able to handle the cookie:

```
if (!cookie) {
    console.log('Cookie not there');
    resp.cookie('FIRST_SIGNUP', 'Hello World', { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 999999 });
} else {
    console.log(cookie);
    console.log('cookie already exists');
}

next();
```