# Empty object with req.session in cookie session express package

Tags: node.js, express, session-cookies, cookie-session

I'm trying to solve that for a long time.  I'm trying to make cookie session using express cookie session and react on the front. Cookie should be in my req.session object but instead it is empty.

Here's my code:

```
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const keys = require('./config');


app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  maxAge: 3000000,
  keys: ['key1', 'key2']
}))

app.get('/t', function (req, res) {

 // here I'm expecting to get cookie object
  res.send(req.session);

})


require('./routes/tasksRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/checkAnswers')(app)

app.listen(5000);
```

Could you help me on that one. Why I'm getting empty object?
Thank you guys!

Comment: where are you setting cookie?

Comment: That't the place I probably misunderstand the cookie conception. I thought the app.use(coockieSession...) set up the cookie. But apparently it is not true. How setting up cookie works then?

Comment: You need to define cookie for user,
like on server, you need to set it for users

Comment: you may want too look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set cookie, what you have done is configure it, now you need to set it in order use it

```
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); 
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const keys = require('./config');


app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  maxAge: 3000000,
  keys: ['key1', 'key2']
}))

// now when you'd hit this URL your user will have a cookie attached to it.
app.get('/s', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue')
});

app.get('/t', function (req, res) {
// you'd be able to see your cookie object here after hitting '/s' API
 // here I'm expecting to get cookie object
  res.send(req.session);

})


require('./routes/tasksRoutes')(app);
require('./routes/checkAnswers')(app)

app.listen(5000);
```

Comment: Thank you! I can set the cookie now and I see it inside of the headers but still cannot receive it while requesting '/t' route.

Comment: what are you using to test API !?

Comment: @Barth if you are using POSTMAN or something like that, it would not maintain session.