# ExpressJS cannot set session id cookie

Tags: javascript, express, setcookie, sessionid, express-session

I have to set a session id from my ExpressJS middleware with a "Set-Cookie" header, that I get from another source. It seems like ExpressJS blocks it. Here is my code snippet:

```js
res.cookie("sessionid", "value-from-backend", {
    domain: ".domain.com",
    httpOnly: true
})
```

Another Set-Cookie header that I tried, works without a problem:

```js
res.cookie("test", "lel", {
    domain: ".domain.com",
    httpOnly: true
})
```

Do I have to use ExpressJS cookie session to get this work or is there a simpler way? And how can I achieve this with ExpressJS cookie session?

My ExpressJS version is: `4.16.3.

It is no duplicate of other Set-Cookie problems, because it is just not working with `sessionid` but with any other cookie name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set cookie in node js using express framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework)

Comment: @lux No it's not because it works with other cookie names. Check my edit.