# How to set the session or cookie in https request to url?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am calling below url with get https request using *Node.js*, here i need to send the session with cookie, since i know the vallue of cookie.

```
var URL = require('url-parse');

var appurl = "https://test.somedomain.com"
var https = require('https');
var url = new URL(appurl);
var options = {
    host: url.host,
    url: appurl,
    path: url.pathname + url.query,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "Set-Cookie": "cookiValue1=abcdesg"
    }
};

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    // console.log(res.headers.)
    // res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ', chunk);
    });
});
req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set cookie in node js using express framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework)

Comment: here i am asking how to send cookie from client side.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain your situation a little more clearly. Or, if this question is closed, please ask another.  Do you want Javascript running in a browser to set a cookie in that browser? Do you want that Javascript to include a cookie in a request to some server?

Answer (score 0):

The header should be `Cookie` instead of `Set-Cookie`

`Set-Cookie`  is used by the server to set a cookie on clients. Header `Cookie` is used to send a cookie to server by client.

Answer (score 0):

So nodejs server it's not a browser which have `window` and `document`

try to send the same request in js client side not nodejs

You can set cookie only here

see POINTERs in the bottom

```
var URL = require('url-parse');
var https = require('https');
var appurl = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
var url = new URL(appurl);
var options = {
    host: url.host,
    url: appurl,
    path: url.pathname + url.query,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        "Cookie": "1111111111=abcdesg", // POINTER its unfortunately useless
        "Set-Cookie": "11111111=abcdesg" // POINTER its unfortunately useless
    }
};

var req = https.request(options, function (res) {
    console.log('before HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
    res.headers.cookiValue1 = 'abcdesg'; // POINTER
    console.log('after HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

});
req.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

req.write('data\n');
req.write('data\n');
req.end();
```