# How do I save my data from my POST request, as a variable, to use in my GET request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, rest

I am receiving my data from my POST request. I want to use that data as a variable in a GET request.The data from the POST request is user inputted to make different queries on the 3rd party API> How can I save my data as a variable to do so? You can see my request.body is being saved as const data. And I need it used as ${data} in my get request. I am pretty new to this, so any suggestions on best practice would be appreciated. Thanks for helping out.

```
Server.js


app.get(`/getmovies`, (req, res) => {

    request(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${data}&apikey=${API_KEY}`,
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
                res.send(parsedBody)

            } else {
                console.log("error in the server")
            }
        }
    )
})


app.post('/postmovie', (request, response) => {
    console.log("I got a request!")
    console.log(request.body);
    const data = request.body;
    response.json({
        status: 'success',
        name: data
    })
})


///Client 

  postMovie = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = this.state.movie;
    const options = {
      method: 'Post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    };

    const response = await fetch('/postmovie', options);
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log(json);


  };



  getMovies = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { movie } = this.state;
    axios.get(`/getmovies`)
      .then(response => this.setState({ movies: response.data }))
      // .then(response => this.setState({ movies: response.data }))
      .catch(err => console.error(err))
  }

  render() {
    const { movie } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <section className="form-container">
          <div className="movie-form-div">


            < form>
              <input className="form-input" type="text" name="name"
                value={movie.name}
                onChange={e => this.setState({ movie: { ...movie, name: e.target.value } })} />
              <button onClick={this.getMovies}>Search</button>
              <button onClick={this.postMovie}>Post</button>

            </form >
          </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a global variable? Otherwise you can't and it makes no sense. They are differently scoped. Furthermore, if node.js is anything like the other web languages, end points will be possibly on different threads (not sure about node). Anyway, you shouldn't do this because you will also lose your data every time the app restarts. Use a database to save information like everyone else

Comment: Just to be clear, setting a global variable also doesn't make sense. Terrible practice.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense to store it into a database, when it is only going to be used one time. It is just a query parameter for a 3rd party api, to display a movie. It could easily be done client side, but an API key is involved.

Comment: why not pass the API key with the application config? I am not seeing why it has to come from the client side? Are they one use keys? Regardless, worst case why not make it a query parameter for the get request? Or set a cookie

Comment: I don't know how to do any of those things, which is why I am asking the question. Haha. It has to come from the client side because it is a variable that the user inputs.

Comment: I am just trying to narrow down what you have tried. Now that we have defined those parameters, let me get you some links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comments, your question is worded such that you make it sound like you absolutely need two requests.

Per the comments, OP has clarified that they don't necessarily need two requests so on that note here are a few things that you can try.

1) Set up an **application.conf**

[Configuration files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_file) allow us to parameterize and configure variables that our applications need to function. You can vary the config files between environments (dev/stage/prod etc.) and deployments.

This will assume your API_KEY doesn't change frequently. Think of it as hard coding your api key like

```
var apiKey = "...."
```

but a better and more secure way of doing so.

In your case this won't work but it is good to be aware of it. You can use [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) in the future

2) Get request query parameters.

**This is your best bet**

Query parameters, as the name suggest, allow us to pass in variables with the get requests to filter the results in the server side. This can be something like a user-id, page number etc.

Your get url from the client side would look like something like this

```
mydomain.com/getmovies?apikey={YourKeyGoesHere}
```

I am sure you have seen that ***?*** in many of the urls you visit.

If you are using **express** your end point will look something like this.

```
app.get(`/getmovies`, (req, res) => {
   var apiKey = req.query.apikey
   request(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${data}&apikey=${apikey}`,
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
            res.send(parsedBody)

        } else {
            console.log("error in the server")
        }
    }
)
})
```

See [How to get GET (query string) variables in Express.js on Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912584/how-to-get-get-query-string-variables-in-express-js-on-node-js)

This will allow you to pass it from the client side.

If you are not using express please see https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html

3) If you absolutely need two endpoints...

Use a cookie. Once a cookie is set, it is transported back and forth with every request, until it expires.

See this [How to set cookie in node js using express framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework) or [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookies)

Once you receive the post request you would set a cookie

```
app.post('/postmovie', (request, response) => {
    response.cookie("apikey", data, maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: true });
    response.json({
      status: 'success'
    })
})
```

Once this cookie is set, it will be transported to the client and back with all the requests including the get.

So in your get request you can do:

```
app.get(`/getmovies`, (req, res) => {
   var apikey = req.cookies.apikey;
   request(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=${data}&apikey=${apikey}`,
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var parsedBody = JSON.parse(body);
            res.send(parsedBody)

        } else {
            console.log("error in the server")
        }
    }
)
})
```

**So what's the difference between #2 and #3?**

The query parameters that are encoded in the url are public and can be intercepted. This is fine for things like page numbers but if the API key is a paid one, this isn't very safe. Also once you submit the query, it is gone (unless you save the api key in the client side to the memory or local storage) so the user will have to potentially re-enter the api key everything.

Cookies on the other hand are private. The **http-only** flag we set in the code, prevents even the browser from reading it. Only the issuing server can see the contents. Plus cookies get stored in the browser until the expiration date so they can be reused with multiple requests.

Pick the one that works for you.

P.S. I didn't test the code above, you may need to tweak it a little bit. The answer is to give you a general idea on how these things are usually handled

Comment: Thank you so much. You answered my question perfectly.

Comment: @HankHill you are welcome. Good luck and happy coding!