# Javascript: How Do I Set Response Object Headers?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing a simple exercise where I use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to interact with another website. The Fetch API resolves to a Response object. My next goal is to set a `cookie` on this Response object, but I noticed that the headers property on the [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object is read-only. Perhaps there is something very simple that I've overlooked, but how can I set a `cookie` in the Response object's header?

Edit: To clarify, the Response object returned by the Fetch call is what I want to return back to the client, but before I do that I want to set a cookie in the header so that the client will have a `cookie` saved.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework

Comment: Um, you don't really *set* stuff on a response you get from *somewhere else*.