# How to set sameSite and Secure attributes in a cookie with express?

Tags: node.js, express

I have this server API code that create a cookie and I needed to set `samesite` and `Secure` attributes to get rid of a warning so I added them like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework) but I get now error

> Request failed with status code 500

```
app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({'email': req.body.email}, (err, user) => {
        if (!user) return res.json({isAuth: false, message: 'Auth failed no email'});

        user.comparePassword(req.body.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (!isMatch) return res.json({isAuth: false, message: 'wrong password'});

            user.generateToken((err, User) => {
                if (err) return res.status(400).send(err);
                res.cookie('auth', user.token, {samesite:none, secure:true}).send({isAuth: true, id: user._id, email: user.email });
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Is this the correct way to set samesite and secure attributes ? how I can fix this ?

Without `{samesite:none, secure:true}` the API work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sameSite:'none'` instead of `samesite:none`