# Cookie not beign set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

i was looking cookies in chrome dev tools and what saw that there was nothing there.
I tried to do

```
document.cookie
''
```

but as you can see i got an empty string.

This is how i set cookie from backend :

```
res.cookie('token', token, {
  maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
});
```

and http response :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Set-Cookie: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MTA0ODNiMWZjYWRjMzJlNThlYzliZGYiLCJpYXQiOjE2Mjc5MDU2ODksImV4cCI6MTYyNzk5MjA4OX0.0Tl9qdfOfYmrSCmhwm4_nj5YJoQ4nIena8GkDVMuudg; Max-Age=86400; Path=/; Expires=Tue, 03 Aug 2021 12:01:29 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 279
ETag: W/"117-n8AH6F39BYaXWbbpDJY0ai6Z4l8"
Date: Mon, 02 Aug 2021 12:01:29 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

I don't know if this is normal. Thanks for any respose.

Comment: I am assuming node.js on backend? Using express?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set cookie in node js using express framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16209145/how-to-set-cookie-in-node-js-using-express-framework)

Comment: Are you using the same session to check document.cookie? i.e. the same as your client application

Comment: @epascarello yes

Comment: @PraveenThirumurugan No , as you can see my problem is not setting cookie

Comment: @PriyankaLad client localhost:3000 backend : localhost:8000