# why JWT token is not storing in cookie

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jwt

I'm trying authenticate user with JWT token.
here is token I'm sending from API

```
  const token = user.getJWToken();
    const options = {
        expires:new Date(
            // convert days into ms
            Date.now + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24*60*60*1000
        ),
        httpOnly:true
    }

    res.status(statusCode).cookie("token",token,options).json({
        success:true,
        user,
        token
    });
```

and here is my app.js for backEnd

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors())
```

now when I'm loggin in Reactjs. no cookies are stored . in postman everything is working fine. it show cookies in postman. but when I using it in frontEnd . no cookies are stored

```
    api.post("/api/v2/users/login", {
        email: loginEmail,
        password: loginPassword
      },{headers:{'Content-Type':"application/json"}})
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        setloggedIn(true);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  };
```

and api is

```
const api = axios.create({
 baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE_URL ,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think

1. your code `res.status(statusCode).cookie("token",token,options).json({...})` may have resulted in malformed JSON as response, depending on how 'user' and 'token' is structured? they both suppose to be key:val pair in your scenario.
2. on the frontend, you still try to add '**withCredentials: true**' as part of option to your axio request. if you are not familiar with this option, you can see some related post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16209531

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem i was using custom publicRequest method to login i solve it by adding {withCredentials: true} as option to request.

Comment: Because this does not seem to add any additional insight, I perceive this as "Thank you" for https://stackoverflow.com/a/71777327/7733418 If that is what you intended, please delete this and upvote the existing answer. Otherwise please [edit] to make more obvious what additional insight your post provides. Ideally according to [answer].

Answer (score -1):

But first, I advise you to use Local Storage because it is better

**Understanding the Problem:**

- The provided code snippets indicate that you're working with Express for your Node.js API and Axios for API calls in React.
- Cookies are not being stored in the browser despite everything seemingly working fine in Postman.

**Possible Causes and Solutions:**

1. **Incorrect Cookie Configuration:**

   - **`path` and `domain` Attributes:** Ensure `path` is set to your application's base path (e.g., `/`). If using subdomains, set `domain` accordingly.
   - **`sameSite` Attribute:** Consider `sameSite` values such as `None` or `Lax` if cross-site requests are involved, but only under a secure connection (HTTPS).
   - **`secure` Attribute:** Use `secure: true` if your application is served over HTTPS.
   - **Example:**

   ```js
   res.cookie("token", token, {
       expires: new Date(Date.now() + process.env.COOKIE_EXPIRE * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
       httpOnly: true,
       path: "/",
       sameSite: "None", // Only use with HTTPS
       secure: true // Only use with HTTPS
   });
   ```
2. **CORS Issues:**

   - If your frontend and backend reside on different domains, properly configure CORS headers in your backend to allow cookies from the frontend domain.
   - Use the `cors` middleware with appropriate settings or manually set CORS headers:

   ```js
   app.use(cors({
       origin: "your-frontend-domain.com", // Adjust accordingly
       credentials: true
   }));
   ```
3. **JavaScript Errors or Cookie Blocking:**

   - Inspect your browser console for any errors related to cookies or JavaScript.
   - Check if your browser has cookie blocking enabled or restrictions like "Prevent cross-site tracking" in Safari.
4. **Browser Compatibility:**

   - Certain browsers or cookie settings might prevent the token from being stored. Test on different browsers and devices.
5. **Server-Side Issues:**

   - Double-check that your backend is actually setting the cookie correctly. Use browser developer tools' Network tab to verify.

**Additional Tips:**

- Leverage `dotenv` or similar library to manage environment variables securely.
- Use stricter `sameSite` values like `Lax` or `Strict` whenever possible for security.
- Consider alternative storage mechanisms like Local Storage or IndexedDB if cookies are unsuitable for your use case.
- Thoroughly test your implementation across different browsers and configurations.