# how to validate a node js cookie with client-side javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

i created this cookie in node js:

```
res.cookie('DKNS', username, {maxAge: 10000 });
```

but it is created in the browser, but I don't know why it is not deleted after 10 seconds, I want it to be deleted after 10 seconds and once it is deleted it will redirect me to my login route, I have this function  in javascript that would serve to check if the cookie exists:

```
function checkCookie(){                              
 if(document.cookie.indexOf("DKNS") == (-1)) {         
  window.location.replace = "/login";                 
 }
setTimeout(checkCookie, 1000)
}
```

but it doesn't work can someone help me with this, please?

Comment: How did you check that your cookie is created in browser?

Comment: so it doesn't check, but it was to check why the javascript function is correct.

Comment: Look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176432/cant-set-cookie-expires-or-maxage-in-node-js-using-express-3-0

Comment: yes friend, it is expiring, but now my problem is ,.  how will I validate this cookie on the client with my javascript function