# I get error when running npm start in vs code

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

```
(node:6852) [LRU_CACHE_OPTION_maxAge] DeprecationWarning: The maxAge option is deprecated. please use options.ttl instead
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)

> mynodejsapp@0.0.0 start
> node ./bin/www

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\MinGW\bin
npm ERR! path C:\Users\TECHNOCITY9645075247\Desktop\web designing\myNodejsApp
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\MinGW\bin ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\TECHNOCITY9645075247\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-13T10_44_05_635Z-debug-0.logenter code here
```

**this is the error showing in the terminal**
my node and npm versions are upto date

Comment: Please, post more information like what kind of apps are you trying to start, node version, npm version, the completed output log and etc....

Comment: node version is 16.14.0 , npm version 8.3.1.I just started learning nodejs.

Comment: npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\MinGW\bin
npm ERR! path C:\Users\TECHNOCITY9645075247\Desktop\Web Development
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent spawn C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe;C:\MinGW\bin ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\TECHNOCITY9645075247\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-03-15T17_17_16_517Z-debug-0.log     this is the error i get when running the app

Answer (score 3):

***Try to reinstall Node.js. Should work as it worked for me.***

**Uninstalling the Node.js**

1. Clear the npm cache by running the following command in your terminal.

   npm cache clean --force
2. Go to the windows control panel and click on Uninstall a program, select Node.js and click on uninstall tab to uninstall the node and npm successfully.

**Restart your system.**

3. Verify if node.js and npm are completely uninstalled from your system using:

   node -v

If the above command prints command not found then you’re successfully uninstalled, otherwise look into the below directories and remove the contents manually.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs
C:\Program Files\Nodejs
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm (or %appdata%\npm)
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache (or %appdata%\npm-cache)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks you're facing the problem of using `maxAge` instead of `expires`
look at this link [Can't set cookie 'expires' or 'maxAge' in Node.js using Express 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176432/cant-set-cookie-expires-or-maxage-in-node-js-using-express-3-0)

Maybe help you for better resolution into the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Node.js.
Should work as it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tried,not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean your cache then reinstall Node.js. Should work as it worked for me.